# When is the annihilator of the commutator subspace a complemented subspace?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital Banach algebra and $C$ be its commutator subspace, i.e., $C$ is the norm-closure of the subspace spanned by the elements of the form $xy-yx$ in $A$.

*Notation:* Let $C^{\perp}=\{f\in A^{*}: C\subseteq kerf\}$ denote the annihilator of $C$, and let $Z(A)$ denote the center of $A$.
Given $a\in A$ and $f\in A^{*}$, $af\in A^{*}$ is defined by $af(x):= f(xa)$ for each $x\in A$.

**Q1:** What are the necessary and (*or*) sufficient conditions that $C^{\perp}$ is a complemented subspace in $A^{*}$?

**Q2:** Suppose $C^{\perp}$ is complemented in $A^{*}$. What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of a projection $P:A^{*}\to C^{\perp}$ satisfying $P(af) = a(Pf)$ for all $a\in Z(A)$ and $f\in A^{*}$?

Comment: By commutator subalgebra, do you really mean the algebra generated by commutators? For example, when $A$ is the full matrix algebra, is it $A$ itself?

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA Thank you for pointing it out. I actually mean the closed linear subspace generated by the commutators. I've just edited the post. The commutator subspace of a full matrix algebra is the set of all matrices with zero trace.

Comment: Your space $C^\perp$ seems to be the same as the space of tracial linear functionals on $A$. I don't think there is a single set of necessary and sufficient conditions for Q1, but in some private calculations I was doing about ten years ago I think I found a proof that this holds if $A$ is a Cstar algebra. I was also able to find a Banach algebra for which $C^\perp$ is not complemented in $A^*$ by indirectly using the result in de la Salle's answer to this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81032/is-the-space-of-hankel-operators-complemented-in-bh

Comment: Also, in Q2, do you really want the chosen projection P to be a Z(A)-module map, or do you just want to know if C^\perp being complemented in A implies the existence of some other projection which is a Z(A)-module map? If it is the weaker version that you are interested in, then I think amenablity of Z(A) would suffice, but I have not checked my calculations

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what was the original motivation for Q1? The problem that motivated me to look at the same question in 2011 came from trying to prove/disprove things about weak amenability of tensor products of Banach algebras

Comment: @YemonChoi Thank you for the link, I need some time to digest though. For Q2, I'm looking for at least one projection that's a Z(A)-module map, not all. I knew that amenability of $A$ suffices, but I can't foresee at the moment if amenability of $Z(A)$ does.

Comment: Regarding the link, that MO question doesn't immediately explain how to build the counterexample. I could send you some notes by email if you don't mind waiting a day or two (I never wrote anything up for publication)

Comment: @YemonChoi I am glad that you've asked, and it'd be great to have your notes - whether published or unpublished. I promise to add up all that I can, but I don't want to (because it's not ethical) oversell myself higher than the worth.

Comment: For Q2, I can't see how to use amenability of $A$, because $C^\perp$ might not be a sub-$A$-module of $A^*$. It is a sub-Z(A)-module, see my answer below.

Comment: @YemonChoi My motivation is/was to find some sufficient (hopefully equivalent) conditions for amenability in the language of Banach spaces, which is a simpler language to me than the homology of Banach algebras.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129935/discussion-between-yemon-choi-and-onur-oktay).

Comment: [deleted a comment, I overlooked the initial assumption that A is unital]

Answer (score 3):

Regarding Q2: note that $C$ is a sub-$Z(A)$-module of $A$. So $C^\perp= (A/C)^*$ is a dual $Z(A)$-module, and by assumption $C^\perp$ is complemented as a Banach space in $A^*$.

Now it follows from general results of Helemskii, see also Curtis-Loy JLMS 1989 Theorem 2.3, that whenever B is amenable, M is a B-module and N is a complemented subspace of M such that N is also a dual B-module, then there is a projection of M onto N that is also a B-module map.

Therefore: if $Z(A)$ is amenable and $C^\perp$ is complemented as a Banach space in $A^*$, it is complemented as a Banach $Z(A)$-module.

(I am being a bit sketchy here, if I find time later I can try to fill in details if something is not clear.)

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of this note is not to answer my own question, but to share a sufficient condition with everyone: If $A$ is amenable, then Q1 & Q2 are answered affirmatively.

---

*Notation:* $A\hat{\otimes}_{\pi} A$ is the projective tensor product of $A$ with itself. For an $A$-bimodule $M$, the bimodule center is defined by $\mathcal{Z}(A,M) =\{\beta\in M: a\beta=\beta a\hspace{4mm} \forall a\in A \}$. $A^{*}$ is identified with the image of the map (dual of the product map) $\sim:A^{*}\to (A\hat{\otimes}_{\pi} A)^{*}$, which is defined by $\widetilde{f}(x\otimes y) =  f(xy)$ on basic tensors (and extended linearly & continuously afterwards).

---

$A$ is amenable if and only if $(A\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}A)^{*} = A^{*} \oplus K$ as a direct sum of $A$-bimodules for some sub-$A$-bimodule $K$ of $(A\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}A)^{*}$, see [Curtis & Loy](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/jlms/s2-40.1.89) . From this, it is not difficult to show that $$\mathcal{Z}(A,(A\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}A)^{*}) = \mathcal{Z}(A,A^{*}) \oplus\mathcal{Z}(A,K)$$ as a direct sum of $Z(A)$-modules.
It is also not difficult to show that every $\beta\in \mathcal{Z}(A,(A\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}A)^{*})$ is given by $$\beta(x\otimes y) = f(yx) \hspace{8mm} \forall x,y\in A$$ for some $f\in A^{*}$, and every $\beta\in\mathcal{Z}(A,A^{*})$ is similarly given by $f\in A^{*}$ with the extra property that $af=fa$ for every $a\in A$. Hence, one may identify $\mathcal{Z}(A,(A\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}A)^{*})$ with $A^{*}$, and $\mathcal{Z}(A,A^{*})$ by $C^{\perp}$ in a natural way via $Z(A)$-module isomorphisms. Similarly, $\mathcal{Z}(A,K)$ is isomorphic to a $Z(A)$-submodule of $A^{*}$, call it $B$. Consequently, $$A^{*} = C^{\perp}\oplus B$$ as a direct sum of $Z(A)$ submodules. In particular, $C^{\perp}$ is a complemented subspace of $A^{*}$.

---

*N.B.:* Amenability is a considerably strong condition compared to the ones given by Q1 & Q2. Thus, it is interesting to see weaker sufficient conditions. On the contrary, Q1/Q2 provides relatively easy to check tests for non-amenability. Thus, it is interesting to see a class of Banach algebras where Q1 or Q2 is not satisfied.

Comment: If $A$ has a Mityagin decomposition, then $A$ has no nonzero traces, e.g. https://www.jstor.org/stable/24715582. In the same paper (Example 3.8), for $E=\ell^p, L^p$ for $1\leq p<\infty$, the algebras $A=B(E)$ have no nonzero traces, so $C^{\perp}=\{0\}$. For the James space $E=J_p$ and $A=B(E)$, $C^{\perp}$ is 1-dimensional, so complemented. Clearly $Z(A)$ is trivial (1-dim.) for these $A$. Thus, Q1 and Q2 are answered affirmatively. Notice that none of these algebras are amenable.